# HQL with parameters NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am sure I am overlooking something obvious

the following static query works fine

```
hqlQuery = "select user from User as user where user.id = 'userid' ";
```

but when I parametrize the query

```
hqlQuery = "select user from User as user where user.id = :me ";
Query query = session.createQuery(hqlQuery);
```

I get a nasty stack dump from building the query.
What am I overlooking?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateNamedParameter(HqlSqlWalker.java:940)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.parameter(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4997)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1413)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3947)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:617)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
```

Answer (score 13):

Problem here is there is a conflict between the two ANT jar files(namely: antlr-2.7.6.jar from Hibernate Jar library & antlr-2.7.2 from struts-1.3) in your project. This appears to be a peculiar problem with Struts-1.3 & Hibernate applications.

Please remove antlr-2.7.2.jar from your project(/WEB-INF/lib folder)& it should work fine.. Let me know if it works..

Comment: The project changed direction, and the question is now moot (to me). I am using struts 1.2. source for bad jar could be from Weblogic Server 9.x

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you mixed incompatible versions of Hibernate jars (probably ANTLR jar has a wrong version).

Answer (score 2):

You can this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably improved if you could explain what's happening and why.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```