# HQL return java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to set parameter in HQL this way:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from Device d " +
                    "left join fetch d.tradeInOldDevice " +
                    "left join fetch d.tradeInNewDevice " +
                    "left join fetch d.warranty "  +
                    "where d.owningCompany.customerRefId =:customerId ");


              query.setString("customerId", "someHardCodeCustomerId");


            Set<Device> customerDevices= (Set<Device>) query.list();
```

I am gettig that error:

ספט 24, 2013

```
2:36:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServicesServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateNamedParameter(HqlSqlWalker.java:945)
```

Hibernate dependcies:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


<!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am running hibernate on tomcat inside Spring container.

I checked maven dependencies in My project I have Maven: antlr:antlr:2.7.2.

What could be wrong here?

thanks.

Comment: Looks like dependency version conflict. Analyze the classpath of the running application and check it against dependencies for Hibernate libraries.

Comment: Is there another way of setting this param? Because without setting params that works ok.

Comment: It's more likely about libraries provided with your application server then build script parameters, but you haven't specified what server you are using and how do you build your war/ear so it's hard to guess.

Comment: @rayman From where `myId` comes session ?

Comment: Think about myId as a hardcoded string

Comment: Check whether you have antlr jar file in your classpath. I do not see major issues with version of antlr jar files, but if you still face the issue, check for the version compatibility between hibernate and antlr.

Comment: I checked maven dependencies in My project I have Maven: antlr:antlr:2.7.2. edited my question

Comment: @rayman but there is a dependency conflict that is why you have this problem one of the dependencies in your project might be using some other version of antlr .

Comment: @rayman please give the hibernate-core dependency version

Comment: possible duplicate of [HQL with parameters NoSuchMethodError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838741/hql-with-parameters-nosuchmethoderror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library conflict. I think you have another version of antlrXXX.jar loaded in web-inf/lib. This is loaded before the one on which hibernate depends on.
Pleasse complete the question with the used hibernate version so that I can reply putting the correct dependency for completness.

Update:
After the comments the conflicting version is 2.7.2.
Check who is importing 2.7.2 using mvn dependency:tree and exclude that transitive dependency in the pom.

Comment: Done. please check question again.

Comment: I checked maven dependencies in my project I have Maven: antlr:antlr:2.7.2

Comment: hibernate uses 2.7.6. remove the other. btw: are u using struts? if you do not declare it directly very likely struts bring it in.

Comment: ok then check who is importing 2.7.2 using mvn dependency:tree and exclude that transitive dependency. If it is not clear I describe the details in the answer above. Let em know

Answer (score 0):

This is because the antlr-2.7.2.jar struts2 and Hibernate antlr-2.7.7.jar conflict, as long as the antlr-2.7.2.jar struts2 file can either remove this problem does not occur. You can try.

If such an error is reported: Then you go to your tomcat application under this WEB WEB-INF Under the lib antlr-2.7.2.jar will be deleted. .