# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine() using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, antlr

I am using Spring and Hibernate and i always get this error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()
```

It happens when i make custom definitions in my repositories:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> 
{
    @Query("select u from User u where username = ?1")
    List<User> findByUsername(String username);

    @Query("select u from User u where username = ?1 and password = ?2")
    List<User> findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

If i remove the 2 queries then everything works just fine.

I also added antlr as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>        
</dependency>
```

but this was unsuccessful to solve my issue.

Spring: `3.2.3 RELEASE`

Hibernate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, i am not using Struts library.

Comment: Could you please post versions of Spring and Hibernate you have?

Comment: @Ordous i have updated my original post with the correct versions

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838741/hql-with-parameters-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: Maxim it may still be possibly a duplicate, as another library may be using another version of antlr. Make a quick check for all the versions you have just to be sure and to avoid further "possible duplicate" comments. As to your question: I cannot really see the @Query annotation being supported in Spring 3.0+ or Hibernate 4.0+. Am I missing something? Can you confirm which library they are coming from?

Comment: I got the Query annotation from this page: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate, spring apparently has a struts dependency

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Spring Boot and this error happened because antlr-2.7.7 used by hibernate-core-4.3.7 was overridden by antlr-2.7.2 used by struts-core-1.3.8.

If someone has this issue in Spring Tool Suite IDE, this is what I did:

- open project's pom.xml
- in Dependency Hierarchy tab select antlr (2.7.2) in Resolved Dependencies list
- in same tab in Dependency Hierarchy list right-click on antlr-2.7.7 and select "Lock Transitive Dependency Version..." and click OK.
- save pom.xml
- run app again

Comment: this solution worked for me once and on another occasion, deleting the 2.7.2 jar from the local repo resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The class `antlr.collections.AST` is an ANTLR v2 class.

For the record, these are the packages of the ANTLR versions:

- ANTLR v2, package: `antlr...`
- ANTLR v3, package: `org.antlr...`
- ANTLR v4, package: `org.antlr.v4...`